# How to get a file from WEB-INF in a JUNIT test

Tags: java, web-applications, junit, classpath

In a controller of a webapp, I am redirecting to some other page (xyz.jpsx) when a given condition is true.

Now, in a Junit test, I want to enforce that the redirect is done correctly, but also that the redirect points to a jsp that actually exists.

I couldn't find a way, inside a Junit, to read files from inside WEB-INF. I don't want to hardcode the fullpath as the solution wont be much portable.

I totally understand the fact that files in WEB-INF are out the classpath, but there might be a way to access theses files. Looking for a portable solution that will also work on my integration server.

Comment: Which framework are you using? Spring MVC?

Comment: Yes, but in my Junit I'm completly detached from the framework.

Comment: So you want to test a spring mvc controller redirect without using the (very good) already existing spring mvc test (org.springframework.test)? Uhm... I don't see how your solution could be portable... It's quite the contrary...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is great [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html) API in JDK 1.7 with class [Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), with help of this class you can easily access to folder with your JSPs (without any ServletContexts or whatever) and do what you need with list of JSP files, here is little sample for you:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class WebInfAccessTest
{
    @Test
    public void shouldListJsps()
    {
        File jspFolder = Paths.get("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages").toFile();
        for (File jsp : jspFolder.listFiles())
            System.out.println(jsp.getName());
    }

}

======================================================================
Here is result for my test Maven project
======================================================================
$ mvn test
...
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running WebInfAccessTest
add.jsp
get.jsp
list.jsp
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.073 sec
```

Comment: Works inside my IDE, but doesn't work when I build the project with maven. Is this normal? Are there work arounds?

Comment: Hey, @BAER, as you can see sample above works with maven using *test* target. I only can assume that you have some custom setting of a root path of your project or something like that, please double-check.

Comment: Hmm I just don't get it running. I honestly don't have an idea, what faulty configuraton I should be looking for. When running the test by maven, the File (in your example "jspFolder") will lead to a NPE when using "listFiles()" or whatever call. Calling "exists()" results in "false". Doing all this via IDE (Intellij in my case) works perfectly. File is found, etc. My maven version is 3.3.3, Java is 1.8.0_131, OS is Win10; but I don't think this would matter really much. Maybe you got some more ideas :/

Comment: One question though @CroWell : What does it print when you call "jspFolder.getAbsolutePath()"? If you debug into the test (mvn -Dtest=YourTest -Dmaven.surefire.debug test) in line "for(File ...", call the absolute path, and go there by hand in the explorer - what do you find? Because, when I do, this folder really doesn't exist: C:\SVN\MyProject\trunk\TheProject\target\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\MyFolder. What is the supposed path, and what could I look for to fix it? As I see it, I "just" need it to stop going into target ... don't know how though

Comment: I've created a own question to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038816/accessing-a-file-in-unit-test-fails-with-maven-but-succeeds-in-ide